# How to get swipe direction in Draggable?

Tags: flutter, dart

Adding this function:

```
 onDragEnd: (drag){
            if(drag.offset.direction > 1){
              print("Swipe left");
            } else {
              print("Swipe right");
            }
          },
```

Does not work for me. I looked for more details in documention, but didn't find the solution. Thank you in advance.

Edit:
This shows only 'swiped' output, still I get no direction:

```
onDragEnd: (drag){
              _removeCard(x);
              log('swiped');
               onDragEnd: (drag){
            if(drag.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.dx < 0){
              log('Swipe left');
            } else {
              log('Swipe right');
            }
          };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `drag.offset` from `DraggableDetails`. Offset only gives you the position. So `drag.offset.direction` only gives you the relative direction of the point relative to the origin.

You are looking to get the swipe direction. So offset won't help. Instead you can use the `velocity` property from `DraggableDetails` and use the `dx` to determine the direction of swipe when the drag ends, which you can get like..

```
onDragEnd: (drag){
            if(drag.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.dx < 0){
              print("Swipe left");
            } else {
              print("Swipe right");
            }
          }
```

However, this only gives you the *direction of the swipe at the time when drag ends*. So if the user's finger is completely still when the drag ends, the `dx` is zero. Another edge case is - for example when the overall swipe is right, but at the time when drag ends, even if the user slightly flicks to left, this will give you left. So if you want to determine the direction of overall swipe, maybe you can compare the x value of the starting and ending offset.